# SSRS Mobile Reports Distinct Count

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Anyone know how to get a distinct count in ssrs 2016 mobile reports?

The built in aggregation only offers a count, not distinct.

Comment: CountDistinct() function can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile reports are extremely limited compared to paginated reports. As you suggested, there's no way to do a distinct count in the visualization, you would need to do it in the dataset beforehand.

Comment: It almost makes sense that there needs to be a round trip to the database to work out the distinct at different levels of aggregation, or there would be quite a lot of work required on the client side and records held at a low granularity. - Just wanted to check that I wasn't missing a trick - looks like paginated for this one! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `CountDistinct()` function in ssrs 2016

More info here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-countdistinct-function

Comment: That works in paginated ssrs reports  it there's no way to use it in Mobile Reports